# PyArrow strptime nanoseconds

Tags: python, strptime, pyarrow

Any idea to parse string time like 10:12:12.123456789 through pyarrow package methods ?

br

tried things like this without success
`pc.strptime(pa.array(["10:12:00.123"]), format="%H:%M:%S.%f", unit="ms")`
returns
`ArrowInvalid: Failed to parse string: '10:12:00.123' as a scalar of type timestamp[ms]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyarrow doesn't support parsing of fractional seconds yet. Support is planned (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-15883) and there is ongoing work on other parts of the parser. I'd guess this will be included in 8.0.0 or 9.0.0 but it's just a guess.

Comment: Ok thank you, im using pandas for the moment
```python
pa.array(
            pandas.to_datetime(array, format="%H:%M:%S.%f"),
            from_pandas=True
        ).cast(pa.time64('ns'), safe=False)
```

Comment: It's not included in 9.0.0

Comment: Indeed it is not.